# How can I apply GZIP content-encoding to an HTTP file upload multipart/form-data POST

Tags: java, http, file-upload, console-application, multipartform-data

I have a custom java console app I am writing to upload non-binary files to a java app server I own.  It is performing an HTTPS multipart/form-data POST with the file to a REST api.  While it works great for small files, I would like to apply GZIP content-encoding to the post request, so it more efficiently handles large files.

Is there a JAVA library I can use to gzip the post, including the file content and then un-zip it on the other side?  I would like to avoid having to zip the file first and would rather rely on HTTP encoding to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

To be pedantic, you wouldn't gzip the entire POST. You would just Gzip the content data, and then in your POST set the Content-Encoding as `gzip`.

You haven't **post**ed your code (**get** it???), so some assumptions need to be made to give an example:

```java
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
...

final String yourData = "butts";
final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final GZipOutputStream gzipOutputStream;

try {
    gzipOutputStream = new GZipOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    gzipOutputStream.write(yourData.getBytes("utf-8"));
} finally {
    gzipOutputStream.close();
}

final byte[] gzippedButts = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

/*
 * Now use the gzipped data as the data in your POST, and also
 * make sure to set the Content-Encoding of your HTTP POST to "gzip".
 */
```

**Edit**: Reading the question again, it sounds like OP wants a library that will abstract away all of the handling and just Gzip a request body under the hood. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any such library.

Comment: The `ByteArrayOutputStream` isn't necessary. It's just a waste of time and space. Just connect the `GZipOutputStream` directly to the real output stream.

Comment: We don't know what OP's "real output stream" is. So I just substituted a BAOS in the example.